# vue v-for index undefined in array object

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2

I have code like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="alert_permission">Izin telah diberikan</div>
        <template v-for="(row, index) in permissions">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="flat-red new-select"
              :key="index"
              :checked="row.name == user_permissions[index].name  ? 'checked' : ''"
              :value="row.name"
              @click="addPermission(row.name)"
            />
            {{ row.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + row.name.slice(1) }}
            <br :key="'row' + index" />
            <br :key="'enter' + index" v-if="(index+1) %3 == 0" />
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my case, I want to checked checkbox when `row.name` is same with data model in array object.
but if write like `user_permissions[0].name` thats work on 1 item only.

How can i use index in that case?

permissions data like

```
[{"id":1,"name":"add course","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05"},{"id":2,"name":"edit course","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05"},{"id":3,"name":"add class","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:05"},{"id":4,"name":"edit class","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":5,"name":"delete class","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":6,"name":"add information","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":7,"name":"edit information","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":8,"name":"delete information","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":9,"name":"add score","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":10,"name":"edit score","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:06"},{"id":11,"name":"delete score","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":12,"name":"edit user","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":13,"name":"delete user","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":14,"name":"add category","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":15,"name":"edit category","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":16,"name":"delete category","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":17,"name":"add module","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:07"},{"id":18,"name":"edit module","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":19,"name":"delete module","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":20,"name":"add presence","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":21,"name":"edit presence","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":22,"name":"delete presence","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":23,"name":"view course","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":24,"name":"view module","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08"},{"id":25,"name":"view score","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09"},{"id":26,"name":"view presence","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09"},{"id":27,"name":"view category","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09"},{"id":28,"name":"view information","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09"},{"id":29,"name":"upload task","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09"}]
```

my user_permissions data like this

```
[{"id":23,"name":"view course","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":23}},{"id":24,"name":"view module","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:08","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":24}},{"id":25,"name":"view score","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":25}},{"id":26,"name":"view presence","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":26}},{"id":27,"name":"view category","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":27}},{"id":28,"name":"view information","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":28}},{"id":29,"name":"upload task","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","updated_at":"2019-10-07 05:30:09","pivot":{"role_id":3,"permission_id":29}}]
```

Comment: Could you please show a sample of that permissions data?

Comment: I have added the data permission

Comment: So are `permissions` and `user_permissions` both arrays and do you want to check the checkbox if any of the entries in `user_permissions` matches the current `row` from `permissions`?

Comment: Is there a point at which the `permissions` value is inserted?

Comment: @skirtle yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `some` to iterate over the other array and check whether any of the entries match the current row:

```
:checked="user_permissions.some(perm => perm.name === row.name)"
```

For small arrays this should be fine. For larger arrays you could speed it up by replacing the inner array with an object that has the permission names as keys and all the values as `true`. Such an object could be created as a computed property and would allow you to skip the inner loop.

Comment: thats work, i just try like this :checked="user_permissions.findIndex(x => x.name == row.name) != -1"

Answer (score 0):

Multiple selection of checkbox must be in the form of array `model`.

When you insert the value of `permissions`, you must insert the result into the checkbox `model` after comparison.

ex)

```html
<div v-for="(row, index) in permissions">
  <input
    v-model="model"  // array type
    type="checkbox"
    :key="index"
    :value="row.name"
  />{{row.name}}
</div>
```

Example code was created in the pen below.
pen - https://codepen.io/kdydesign/pen/QWWwBmx?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I have just cooked something by looking at your data and code. I have not tested it myself but I hope you can see what am trying to do.

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="alert_permission">Izin telah diberikan</div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="flat-red new-select"
              v-model="selectedPermissions"
              v-for="permission in permissions"
              :key="permission.id"
              :checked="userHasPermission(permission.name)"
              :value="permission.name"
              @click="addPermission(permission.name)"
            />{{ permission.name | ucwords }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            selectedPermissions: [],
            permissions; [],
            user_permissions: [],
        }
    },
    mounted ()  {
        // this.permissions = /* call api service to get all permissions */
        // this.user_permissions = /* call api service to get user permissions */
    },
    filters: {
        ucwords (value) {
            const words = String(value).split(/\s+/)
            return words.map(word => {
                let temp = word.trim() 
                return temp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + temp.slice(1)
            }).join(' ');
        },
    },
    methods: {
        userHasPermission (permissionName) {
            let index = this.user_permissions.findIndex((user_permission) => {
                return user_permission.name === permissionName
            })

            return index !== -1
        },

        addPermission (permissionName) {

        }
    }

}
</script>
```

I hope it helps.